# Qlik sense ignore filters / selections

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Using qlik sense

I have the following measure

RangeAvg(Below(Count( Distinct  {1< Year=>} [OrderID]), 0, 52))

I still need  when a user selects a year from the filer pane , the measure is unaffected

however using the Year= does not work

Any ideas team please?

Answer (score 2):

The set identifier of `1` represents "the full set of all the records in the application, irrespective of any selections made." If you want all user selections to be accounted for except for `Year`, simply change the set identifier to `$` (assuming you've not set up and used any other alternate states). The `$` set identifier refers to the default state; the one that selections are made in by default when the user selects something in the interface.

Comment: I have tried this with the dollar sign..  no joy..any more ideas team

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore all filters but the year you can try this following code:

```
RangeAvg(Below(Count(Distinct{1<Year = p(Year)>} [OrderID]), 0, 52))
```

*p* function mean all possible values

For more information, you can read this [help section](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) from the Qlik site